# Long path lengths associated with Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers (Kepler) in Windows XP

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, path

I am trying to set-up "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" (Kepler) on Windows XP Pro SP3 with a roaming profile.  After extracting the directory from the zip file, I placed the folder in C:\Program Files.  At some point, Eclipse placed a .eclipse folder (Which apparently contains configuration files) within the C:\Documents and Settings[username]\ directory.  After several levels of sub-directories, the path length is too long for Windows to handle (Specifically in the case of synchronizing the roaming profile).  The path length ends up being more than 260 characters (above the 255 character windows limit).  This causes unacceptable problems when synchronizing a roaming profile.  A shorter path length should eliminate this particular problem.

Can this .eclipse directory be placed in another directory closer to the root directory?  If so, how do I do redirect Eclipse to the alternate directory to look for its config files?

Also, what strategy can I use to mitigate path length issues in general while developing using Java?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: (1) Extract eclipse to `c:\eclipse`. Make sure it's **not** extracted to `c:\eclipse\eclipse`. (2) Maybe add `%HOME%` to your user path (or system path if you are the only user) and set it to `C:\Users\<USERNAME>`, **although this may interfere with other programs**. (3) Move your eclipse workspaces to `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\<WORKSPACE>`. Hope that helps. (4) Upgrade to Windows-7 :)